# Passing connection variables from xml to powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm trying to create a SQL powershell script to check for certain conditions on multiple SQL servers. The list of servers I would like to connect to are stored in an XML file. The idea is that powershell will parse the XML file and log into each server one at a time. I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm new to powershell so maybe it is something easy I am not doing?

Here is abbreviated XML that lists only 3 servers:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1">   <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Data.DataRow</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Data.DataRow</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="InstanceName">SERVER1\INSTANCE1</S>
      <S N="DatabaseName">master</S>
    </Props>   </Obj>   <Obj RefId="1">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>System.Data.DataRow</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="InstanceName">SERVER1\INSTANCE2</S>
      <S N="DatabaseName">master</S>
    </Props>   </Obj>   <Obj RefId="2">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>System.Data.DataRow</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="InstanceName">SERVER2\INSTANCE1</S>
      <S N="DatabaseName">master</S>
    </Props>   </Obj> </Objs>
```

Here is the part of the code I am having trouble with:

```
$filepath="\\Server\Test\SQLServerInfo.xml" [xml]$xml = Get-Content $filepath

$group = $xml.Objs.Obj.Props

# Parse the XML file  
     foreach ($i in $group) {

             $CurrentServer = $i.S.Item(0)
             $CurrentDB = $i.S.Item(1)

             $CurrentServer   # Show value of variable
             $CurrentDB       # Show value of variable

        # Connect to the SQL Server
            $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$CurrentServer;Database=$CurrentDB;Integrated Security=SSPI"
            $SqlConnection.ConnectionString
            $SqlConnection.Open()
```

The script fails saying server not found or not accessible.

Interestingly when I print the variables to the screen as above ($CurrentServer and $CurrentDB), the values are correct. However, if I change those 2 lines to:

Write-Host "$CurrentServer"
Write-Host "$CurrentDB"

I get the following output:

System.Xml.XmlElement
System.Xml.XmlElement

Further when I tell the script to show the $SqlConnection.ConnectionString after assigning the variables it again shows System.Xml.XmlElement and not the actual variable. So, I'm not getting something with how these variables are assigned via XML.

My question is how to I get my variable into the connection string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as your connection string:

```
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$($CurrentServer.'#text');Database=$($CurrentDB.'#text');Integrated Security=SSPI"
```